# Background color of a div doesn't work

Tags: html, css

One of my Div element is acting very strange. When I write something inside the div it shows it's background color (sticking to the text). But if I dont write anything the background color disappears.

Image with Text:

[image: Image with text:]

Image without Text:

[image: Image without Text]

Here is the html code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: bebas;
}
header {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 80px;
}
#leftRuler {
  width: 15%;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  background: #f3af9d;
}
#bannerContent {
  width: 70%;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  background: #e8603c;
  line-height: 80px;
}
#rightRuler {
  width: 15%;
  right: 80px;
  background: #f3af9d;
  float: left;
}
#logo {
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  display: block;
  color: #e8603c;
}
#menu {
  float: right;
}
#menu ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
}
#menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #b9b9b9;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid e8603c;
}
#menu ul li .current {
  border-bottom: 2px solid e8603c;
  color: e8603c;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div id="headerContent">
    <div id="logo">
      JETRO
    </div>
    <nav id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="current">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</header>

<section id="banner">
  <div id="leftRuler">

  </div>
  <div id="bannerContent">
    Blog
  </div>
  <div id="rightRuler">

  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Typo - `#rightRuler` has `right: 80px;`. It looks like you mean to have `height: 80px`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without content, that "#rightRuler" div doesnt have a height, so its not shown.

set a height or add at least an `&npsp;` character in it

Comment: misterManSam is right, i think its just a typo ;-)

Comment: If a problem in a question is caused by a typo, then don't leave an answer. Make a comment and when you have the rep to do so, vote for the question to be closed. Questions with typos don't help future visitors and should be closed and eventually deleted.

Comment: i saw that too late - i allready had postet the answer, then read your comment.

Answer (score -1):

please mention details what output u exactly want.

according to my understanding u want background color for right div also right?

so for that u only need to change u r css as given below:

```
#rightRuler {
    width: 15%;
    right: 80px;
    background: #f3af9d;
    float: left;
}
```

**to corrected css:**

```
#rightRuler {
    width: 15%;
    height: 80px;
    background: #f3af9d;
    float: left;
}
```

**at place of right just mention height.**

Comment: If a problem in a question is caused by a typo, then don't leave an answer. Make a comment and when you have the rep to do so, vote for the question to be closed. Questions with typos don't help future visitors and should be closed and eventually deleted.